# Processing HashMap of crew details

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap

Enviroment: Java 7

I have a hashmap 'pdf' of Aircrew details  that has the following key structure:

```
public static Map<String, String> pdf;

PilotName JONES
PilotFirstname Jim
PilotID 12345
PilotLicense AAD987
PilotDOB 12/12/2001
PilotGender Male
PilotEthnicity
PilotAddress 123 Any Street
CopilotName SMITH
CopilotFirstname Thomas
CopilotID 987654
CopilotLicense AAB9475
CopilotAddress 456 Any Street
CopilotDOB 12/03/1987
CopilotGender Male
CopilotEthnicity European

CabinManagerSurname
CabinManagerFirstName BROWN
CabinManagerID 48573
CabinManagerDOB
CabinManagerGender
CabinManagerEthnicity
CabinManagerAddress 
Hostess1Surname
Hostess1FirstName
HostessID
Hostess1DOB
Hostess1Gender
Hostess1Ethnicity
Hostess1Address 789 Any Street
Hostess2Surname EDWARDS
Hostess2FirstName Mary
HostessID 475804
Hostess2DOB 11/10/1990
Hostess2Gender Female
Hostess2Ethnicity European
Hostess2Address
Hostess3Surname
Hostess3FirstName
Hostess3ID 489282 
Hostess3DOB
Hostess3Gender
Hostess3Ethnicity
Hostess3Address
```

NB: The field names for crew and pilots are different (Surname/Name Firstname/FirstName).

I want to test if any of certain fields are not empty then call createPerson() method.

The fields to be tested differ for Cabin Crew from Pilots.

I made this attempt but the code is ugly:

```
List<String> pilotRoles = ["Pilot", "Copilot"];
List<String> cabinRoles = ["CabinManager", "Hostess1", "Hostess2", "Hostess3"];


for (String role : pilotRoles) {
    if ( String.isNotNullOrEmpty(pdf.get(pilotRole +"Name")) || String.isNotNullOrEmpty(pdf.get(pilotRole +"Firstname")) || String.isNotNullOrEmpty(pdf.get(pilotRole +"ID")) || String.isNotNullOrEmpty(pdf.get(pilotRole +"License"))) {
                listPeople.add(createPerson(pdf, pilotRole));

for (String role : cabinRoles) {
    if ( String.isNotNullOrEmpty(pdf.get(cabinRole +"Surname")) || String.isNotNullOrEmpty(pdf.get(cabinRole +"FirstName")) || String.isNotNullOrEmpty(pdf.get(cabinRole +"ID")) ) {
                listPeople.add(createPerson(pdf, cabinRole));
```

For the above data the createPerson routine would be entered for both pilots as at least 1 of the tested fields is not null or empty.

The createPerson routine would NOT be entered for hostess1 and all of the tested fields are null or empty.

Is there a more elegant way? If so how.

Comment: That more seems to be List rather than Map. I'm not sure about code, but your question looks ugly

Comment: Why do you use HashMap instead of a JavaObject for representing your aircrew ?

Comment: Its the way it comes to me. I have no control over that.

Comment: What do you received, what can you update, what do you want ? An [mcve] would be nice because this is really not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this: In addition to your lists of roles, create an additional list that holds the names of all attributes, like "Name" etc.

Then you can then create a function to filter your roles for fields that are missing in your `pdf` map, like this:

```
private List<String> getRolesOfMissingUsers(Map<String, String> pdf, List<String> roles, List<String> attributes) {
    return roles.stream().filter(role -> attributes.stream().map(attribute -> role + attribute)
                         .anyMatch(roleAttribute -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(pdf.get(roleAttribute))))
                         .collect(toList());
}
```

You can then use the result of this method to create your missing users. Here is an example just for your pilot rules:

```
for (String role : getRolesOfMissingUsers(pdf, pilotRoles, Arrays.asList("Name", "Firstname", "ID", "License"))) {
    listPeople.add(createPerson(pdf, role));
}
```

EDIT: I noticed you're on Java 7, so you could try this instead:

```
for (String role : pilotRoles) {
  for (String attribute : Arrays.asList("Name", "Firstname", "ID", "License")) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pdf.get(role + attribute))) {
      listPeople.add(createPerson(pdf, role));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If you extract this to a method and pass the list of attributes as a parameter, you should also be able to use this for your crew and pilot list.